# JQuery loop through nested gridview

Tags: jquery, loops, gridview, nested

Is there anyway to loop through a nested gridview? This is the javascript I have so far, I don't think I'm far off a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=gvAdmin.ClientID %> tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find(".gvSubMain tr").each(function() {
            var hdnDate = $(this).find(".Date").val();
            //Do Stuff
        });
    });
});
```

The two gridviews are; a major gridview called gvAdmin, and the nested gridview called gvSubAdmin.
I have looked at this problem for quite a while and see variations such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=gvAdmin.ClientID %> tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find(".gvSubMain > tr").each(function() {
            var hdnDate = $(this).find(".Date").val();
            //Do Stuff
        });
    });
});
```

And another variation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=gvAdmin.ClientID %> tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find(".gvSubMain").find("tr").each(function() {
            var hdnDate = $(this).find(".Date").val();
            //Do Stuff
        });
    });
});
```

But none of these work, is it a small syntax problem that I'm struggling with or is it something in my logic? Do I need to used the `.find(".gvSubMain")` or can I call the gridview some other way?

Thanks,

Firstcape

Comment: Have you put this code in document.ready?

Comment: Sorry yes, I should have stated that, the jQuery here is all wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=gvAdmin.ClientID %> > tbody > tr").each(function () {
        $(this).find(".gvSubMain > tbody > tr").each(function () {
            var hdnDate = $(this).find(".Date").val();
            //Do Stuff
        });
    });
});
```